# PlayFramework 2.2.6: Advanced HTTP server configuration maxInitialLineLength

Tags: rest, playframework, netty, playframework-2.2

We are trying to send GET and POST requests with a length greater than 4096 bytes to our REST API implemented with Playframework 2.2.6.

After a long google research we tried nearly everything and the solution seems to be passing the following two arguments when starting our server via play. We receive no error message about wrong parameters but when we send a large request to the api we still receive the error

```
TooLongFrameException: An HTTP line is larger than 4096 Bytes
```

We are running the server by the following command

```
<PathToPlay>\play-2.2.6\play.bat -org.jboss.netty.maxHeaderSize:102400 -org.jboss.netty.maxInitialLineLength:102400 run
```

Comment: Try to run sbt with -Dhttp.netty.maxInitialLineLength=102400

Comment: Do you know where sbt is called in Play? It's our first time working with PlayFramework.

Comment: You are in production mode so, my bad, it is not in sbt, but you can provide this option exactly the same way you are doing it i.e. replace -org.jboss.netty.maxInitialLineLength:102400 by -Dhttp.netty.maxInitialLineLength=102400

Comment: If we use = instead of : we get an invalid argument error and play suggest us to use :. If we use Dhttp.netty.maxInitialLineLength=102400 we receive a Warning invalid system property.

Comment: Ok, so I'm sorry but it seems not to be the same options on Play! 2.2 that Play! 2.4 (because it works on Play! 2.4). And the ":" instead of "=" is probably because you're on Windows.

Comment: OK thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your path to start your application seems off. When you [create a new play application](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/NewApplication) a `play.bat` or `activator.bat` file is automatically created in your project root folder. So no need to call a specific play installation runtime outside your project folder.

The parameters for setting the max body and header length can be found in the [play documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration#Advanced-HTTP-server-configuration).

> `http.netty.maxInitialLineLength`
>   - The maximum length for the initial line of an HTTP request, defaults to 4096
>
> `http.netty.maxHeaderSize` 
>   - The maximum size for the entire HTTP header, defaults to 8192

## Development Mode

To start your application in *development* mode call

```
/path/to/project/play run -Dhttp.netty.maxInitialLineLength=102400 -Dhttp.netty.maxHeaderSize=102400
```

If you've used Activator to create your project replace `play` with `activator`.

## Production mode

After you've [published your application](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist) for production with `play dist` you can set the parameters by calling

```
/path/to/publishedApp/bin/<nameOfApp> -Dhttp.netty.maxInitialLineLength=102400 -Dhttp.netty.maxHeaderSize=102400
```

Comment: We've got the project from our university, so we didn't started from scratch and funnily enough there's no play in our project root folder.
We've tried to start the server as you mentioned but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Could you please paste the content of `project/plugins.sbt` file, specifically the com.typesafe.play sbt-plugin version?

Comment: // Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.6")